# What multimedia support should I use in centOS 7

Tags: linux, vlc, centos

I have recently installed Cent OS7. Its looks very nice at first.
But soon realized it has a horrible multimedia support. Its own player cannot install the codecs it requires, which was much easier in Debian OS.
When I tried to manually install VLC using `yum install vlc`, it just showed a list of dependency problems:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.11-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libopenjpeg.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.11-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
Error: Package: libcddb-1.3.2-8.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libcdio.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libgme.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libdc1394.so.22()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.11-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libcdio_paranoia.so.0()(64bit)
           Available: libcdio-0.77-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               libcdio_paranoia.so.0()(64bit)
           Installed: libcdio-0.92-1.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               Not found
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libudev.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.11-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libcdio_cdda.so.0(CDIO_CDDA_0)(64bit)
           Available: libcdio-0.77-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               libcdio_cdda.so.0(CDIO_CDDA_0)(64bit)
           Installed: libcdio-0.92-1.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               Not found
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.11-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.11-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libcelt0.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.11-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libcdio_paranoia.so.0(CDIO_PARANOIA_0)(64bit)
           Available: libcdio-0.77-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               libcdio_paranoia.so.0(CDIO_PARANOIA_0)(64bit)
           Installed: libcdio-0.92-1.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               Not found
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libproxy.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: libcddb-1.3.2-8.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libcdio.so.10(CDIO_10)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.11-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libcdio_cdda.so.0()(64bit)
           Available: libcdio-0.77-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               libcdio_cdda.so.0()(64bit)
           Installed: libcdio-0.92-1.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               Not found
Error: Package: librtmp-2.3-3.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libtiger.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libmtp.so.8()(64bit)
           Available: libmtp-0.3.7-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               libmtp.so.8()(64bit)
           Installed: libmtp-1.1.6-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
              ~libmtp.so.9()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.11-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libdc1394.so.22()(64bit)
Error: Package: librtmp-2.3-3.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Is it possible at all to install it in Cent OS 7?
So far I can only find some solutions for Cent OS 6 or lower, which is hardly helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your yum repos were not configured correctly as el6 packages were showing up. Try removing rpmfusion-free-updates, linuxtech-release, and rpmforge. You can add Epel7 and Atrpms el7 repos to solve the problem.